# Why is it called 'Breaking Shabbos'?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat

The standard English language way of referring to חילול שבת seems to be 'breaking Shabbos'. I have not come across the Hebrew phrase 'לשבור את השבת' anywhere, which is the literal translation of 'breaking Shabbos'.

Where does it come from to refer to חילול שבת as 'breaking'?

Comment: "rule breaking"

Comment: Also breaking a fast...

Comment: Lev 26:15 (and elsewhere) in the KJV h-f-r is translated as break (related to covenant/laws). Dawn breaking and break-fast are probably functions of English (I'd have to check my OED).

Comment: I feel this is a function of English and nothing to do with Judaism

Comment: The root חלל can also be understood as "breaking" in the sense of breaking a vow like is used in Sifrei BeMidbar 134:5. In other words, to profane or desecrate.